# About loading huge data into table using load infile command

Tags: mysql

I am getting problem while loading a comma separated txt file into a table. File is huge. Its size is **2 GB** and contains **65 columns** and **34 Lac** rows. I did following setting for loading this file :

- `Query-LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filename INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;`

And In file `my.ini` I added following variables

- `[mysqld] max_allowed_packet=60M`
- `[myisamchk] key_buffer_size=512M myisam_max_sort_file_size=3G`

I am new to mysql. Can anybody help me to load this file. When I run above query I got following result 4-5 times.

```
Query OK,0 rows affected(25.09 sec)
Records:0 Deleted:0 Skipped:0 Warnings:0
```

Answer (score 1):

use external ulil

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-optionally-enclosed-by="\"" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password YOUR_DATABASE tablename.txt
```

Comment: I got this again after firing mysqlimport tablename: Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: thanks Chasing Death and Triclosan.. This issue is a blocker please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try not using the LOCAL keyword,
If this does not solve your problem, post some first lines of the text file so we can see if all the lines are being ignored for not matching the patterns specified in the parameters.

**Update 1:**
Now I see you are using the '\r\n' terminator in

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Have you tried modify this line to use only '\n':

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

?

**Update 2:**
Try specify the table columns in LOAD DATA command;

```
LOAD DATA INFILE filename
INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'(
`tableColumn1` , `tableColumn2`, ..., `tableColumn65`
)
```

Possibly the number of columns of file and table are not matching, or the file columns are not in the same order of the table columns.

Comment: To Jeferson Oliveira : When I copy 10000-15000 rows from source file into a new text file and use above command it inserts those many values without any error my friend.

Comment: and yippe I've tried this with **LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'** also

Comment: Have you tried without using LOCAL keyword? Which MySQL server version are you using? Windows or Linux server? Could you show us a real "filename"? There are problems with some file names on Windows servers.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question myself.

1.I **splitted my file with gslipts** software and did changes accordingly to each of the newly created file.

2.After that I opened these files **in excel formatted** correctly for half an hour and then **created csv file** of each split(files created by gslipts) and **fired load data command**.

Answer (score 0):

When your INFILE is huge, max_allowed_packet must be adjusted to accommodate a max of 1G per this link in the refman for 5.6. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet
 Preparation could include for the 'session' SET local_infile=1;  SET max_allowed_packet=1073741824 (possibly more options required) before LOAD DATA INFILE filename INTO TABLE tablename .....
filename could require full path ie.   C:\folder\subfolder\myfilename.ext

Warning changing max_allowed_packet in your .ini/.cfg to 1G will likely cause unexpected memory stress in your daily operations.  Use your session variables to cover this 1G requirement for the duration of this session.  If you do not have 1G of memory available for this purpose, you can not be successful anyway.